# How do I install psfig.sty in MacTeX?

Tags: packages, installing, mactex

I just installed MacTeX, and I'm trying to compile a document, but I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `psfig.sty' not found.
```

The preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{psfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
  %\singlespacing
  %\onehalfspacing
  \doublespacing
\usepackage{mathptm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

I tried updating everything using TeX Live Utility, but that didn't fix it.

Where can I find `psfig.sty` and how do I install it?

Comment: `psfig` is a *very* obsolete package. Use `graphicx`

Comment: Further to @egreg's comment: Rather use `\usepackage{graphicx}` and then use `\includegraphics{file}`. `graphicx` searches for the appropriate file extension (`.pdf`, `.eps`, ...) and if you're using `pdflatex`, conversion from PS to EPS should be automated.

Comment: Thank you both! How do I close out this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To allow this question to be closed, I'll wrap up the above comments by egreg and Werner into a short answer.*

`psfig` is an obsolete package that should not be used anymore.  Instead, use `graphicx`.  This allows you to insert an external file `name.ext` by using the command `\includegraphics{name}` where `.ext` is automatically appended from a list of appropriate file extensions, such as `.pdf`, `.eps`, `.png`, `.jpg`, …  The exact list of extensions depends (a) on your driver (e.g., pdftex) and (b) on the manually selected list of extensions specified by `\ DeclareGraphicsExtensions{…}`.  Read more about `graphicx` here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics

Comment: It may be obsolete, but the OP was asking how to deal with a document that uses this package.  So saying "don't use it" is not a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem

```
! LaTeX Error: File `psfig.tex' not found.
```

by downloading the file `psfig.tex` from [here](http://arxiv.org/macros/psfig.tex) and putting it in the same directory as the file I was converting.  Then the formatting worked fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The default package repository is available from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psfig).

Comment: @werner: yes, and the ctan catalogue says it's non-free (nosell, in this case).  that's why it's not in tex live, and consequently not in mactex.

Comment: @lockstep, psfig.tex must be renamed to psfig.sty then it works fine.